# How to compare object by properties

Tags: php, arrays, object

I'm trying to compare objects by their properties. I'd like to compare them by their hotelId property. The hotelId is unique for each hotel. For example if I have array of objects like this:

```
   array(4) [
       0 => stdClass(5) {
          hotelId => 238
          hotelName => "Bellevue Dominican Bay" (22)      
       }
       1 => stdClass(5) {
          hotelId => 5432
          hotelName => "Puerto Plata Village" (20)
       }
       2 => stdClass(5) {
          hotelId => 238
          hotelName => "Puerto" (20)
       }
    ]
```

What I am trying to do is to have unique objects with their hotelId.

My code sofar:

```
$uniqueHotelObjects = array();
foreach($arrayOfHotelObjects as $hotel){
    foreach ($uniqueHotelObjects as $uniqueHotel) {
        if($hotel->hotelId !==  $uniqueHotel->hotelId){
            //??   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to do when you find a duplicate?

Comment: When I have a duplicate I want to keep only one object (the first one)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the ID as the array key, you only need one loop:

```
$uniqueHotelObjects = array();
foreach($arrayOfHotelObjects as $hotel){
    // check if the element already exists in the unique array
    if (!array_key_exists($hotel->hotelId, $uniqueHotelObjects) {
        $uniqueHotelObjects[$hotel->hotelId] = $hotel;
    }
}
```

If you want to keep the last entry instead, you can simply remove the `if` statement.